# Nifi java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.reloadExistingConfigurations

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-nifi, hdf

I am following this link to set up Nifi putHDFS to write to Azure Data Lake.[Connecting to Azure Data Lake from a NiFi dataflow](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/71916/connecting-to-azure-data-lake-from-a-nifi-dataflow.html)

The Nifi is within HDF 3.1 VM and the Nifi version is 1.5.

We got the jar files mentioned in the above link, from a HD Insight(v 3.6, which supports hadoop 2.7) head node, these jars are:

```
adls2-oauth2-token-provider-1.0.jar

azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.1.4.jar

hadoop-azure-datalake.jar

jackson-core-2.2.3.jar

okhttp-2.4.0.jar

okio-1.4.0.jar
```

And they are copied to the folder /usr/lib/hdinsight-datalake of the HDF cluster Nifi host(we only have 1 host in the cluster). And the putHDFS config(picture) is as attached(exactly as the link above)[putHDFS attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W4Ky.png).

But in the nifi log we are getting this:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.reloadExistingConfigurations()V at org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlConfKeys.addDeprecatedKeys(AdlConfKeys.java:112) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlFileSystem.(AdlFileSystem.java:92) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) at org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.AbstractHadoopProcessor$ExtendedConfiguration.getClassByNameOrNull(AbstractHadoopProcessor.java:490) at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099) at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:172) at org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.AbstractHadoopProcessor$1.run(AbstractHadoopProcessor.java:322) at org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.AbstractHadoopProcessor$1.run(AbstractHadoopProcessor.java:319) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698) at org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.AbstractHadoopProcessor.getFileSystemAsUser(AbstractHadoopProcessor.java:319) at org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.AbstractHadoopProcessor.resetHDFSResources(AbstractHadoopProcessor.java:281) at org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.AbstractHadoopProcessor.abstractOnScheduled(AbstractHadoopProcessor.java:205) ... 16 common frames omitted

The AdlConfKeys class is from the hadoop-azure-datalake.jar file above. From the above exception, it seems to me this AdlConfKeys is loading an older version of the org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration class, which does not have the reloadExistingConfigurations method. However we cannot find out from where this older class gets loaded. This HDF 3.1 has the hadoop-common-XXXX.jar in multiple locations, all those on version 2.7 something has the org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration containing the method reloadExistingConfigurations, only those on version 2.3 don't have this method.(I decompiled both 2.7 and 2.3 jars to find out)

```
[root@NifiHost /]# find . -name *hadoop-common*
```

(the output is a lot more than below, however I removed some for display purpose, most of them are on 2.7, only 2 of them are on version 2.3):

```
./var/lib/nifi/work/nar/extensions/nifi-hadoop-libraries-nar-1.5.0.3.1.0.0-564.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar

./var/lib/ambari-agent/cred/lib/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar

./var/lib/ambari-server/resources.backup/views/work/WORKFLOW_MANAGER{1.0.0}/WEB-INF/lib/hadoop-common-2.7.3.2.6.2.0-205.jar

./var/lib/ambari-server/resources.backup/views/work/HUETOAMBARI_MIGRATION{1.0.0}/WEB-INF/lib/hadoop-common-2.3.0.jar

./var/lib/ambari-server/resources/views/work/HUETOAMBARI_MIGRATION{1.0.0}/WEB-INF/lib/hadoop-common-2.3.0.jar

./var/lib/ambari-server/resources/views/work/HIVE{1.5.0}/WEB-INF/lib/hadoop-common-2.7.3.2.6.4.0-91.jar

./var/lib/ambari-server/resources/views/work/CAPACITY-SCHEDULER{1.0.0}/WEB-INF/lib/hadoop-common-2.7.3.2.6.4.0-91.jar

./var/lib/ambari-server/resources/views/work/TEZ{0.7.0.2.6.2.0-205}/WEB-INF/lib/hadoop-common-2.7.3.2.6.2.0-205.jar

./usr/lib/ambari-server/hadoop-common-2.7.2.jar

./usr/hdf/3.1.0.0-564/nifi/ext/ranger/install/lib/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar

./usr/hdf/3.0.2.0-76/nifi/ext/ranger/install/lib/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar
```

So I really don't know how Nifi managed to find a hadoop-common jar file or something else containing the Configuration class does not have the method reloadExistingConfigurations(). We do not have any customized Nar files deployed to Nifi either, everything is pretty much default from whatever HDF 3.1 has on Nifi.

Please advise. I've been spending a whole day on this but can't fix the issue. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Azure JARs you are using require a newer version of hadoop-common than the 2.7.3 one that NiFi is using.

If you look at the Configuration class from 2.7.3 there is no "reloadExistingConfiguration" method:

https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.3-RC2/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.java

It appears to be introduced sometime during 2.8.x:

https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.8.3-RC0/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.java

Comment: Bryan appreciate your quick reply ! You are right. The reason I ran into this is I accidentally copied a hadoop-common jar of version 3.0 (and opened/decompiled to find it does contain that method)and thought it's a 2.7 version that I got from the HDF ! Let me try to include the 2.8 version one into our jar list and see what will happen. Will update.

Comment: No problem. It is going to be tough because NiFi's processors include 2.7.3, so even if you put 2.8.x into your directory, it is likely non-deterministic about which JAR it will find the Configuration class from. You may end up needing to build your own version of the NiFi Hadoop NARs setting the hadoop.version in NiFI's root pom to 2.8.3, but I have no idea if this presents any other issues.

Comment: Thanks again Bryan for the further explanation! Yeah I did try my luck knowing it may not work...by adding a hadoop-common-3.0.jar to the nifi lib/bootstrap folder, didn't work; then try merged this jar with the Azure jar files, didn't work either. I guess this relates to how Nifi loads the classes, it'll ask for its parent class loader to find the class first, which in this case the parent class will give the older version of the Configuration class that it has in its class loading path...